# Classification when training data contains probability

Tags: probability, classification, scikit-learn

I am trying to use basic classification algorithms in Python using sklearn. Unfortunately my dependent variable in training data are probabilities of whether it will rain or not. I know how to do this if my dependent variable is "rain" or "sunny". But now it is a probability. Can I use sklearn classification algorithms for this problem or should I use regression? Please advise.

Comment: After googling a bit, I realized that I could convert the [0,1] probability into a normally distributed variable using log (1 / (1 - x)) transformation and then run the regressions. I am still unsure how to solve this as a classification problem.

Comment: If you have the base counts the probabilities came from (the denominator of the prob calculation), you can easily alter data to use classification algorithms.

Comment: Otherwise you could try what you suggest, but Beta regression is developed specifically for this type of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any chance to model a continuous output between [0,1] as a classification problem.

Use regression with P('Sunny') as the target variable.